# What is $3^{\sqrt2}$? Definition of irrational Powers

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

What is $3^{\sqrt2}$ ?

Clearly we can say that $a^m = a \times a \times ...\times a \times a$ **(m times)**

That is  $$3^2=3 \times 3 $$

But how can we define $3^{\sqrt2}$ ? How to understand the definition of irrational Powers ?
I do not need the value. I need a definition to understand this.

Comment: It is a real number greater than $3$ but less than $9$.

Comment: it is the limit of the sequence $3,3^{1.4}, 3^{1.41}, \ldots$

Comment: And it is also $\exp(\sqrt2\ln3)$.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close - this seems a reasonable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're comfortable with exponentiation with rational exponents.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim x_n = \sqrt 2$.
Then $3^{\sqrt2} = \lim 3^{x_n}$.

One such sequence is
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac12\left(x_n + \frac2{x_n}\right), \quad x_0=2.
$$

Comment: Yes ! Can you give me a sequence of rational numbers which converge to $\sqrt{2}$ ? Thank you

Comment: @AngeloMark Think decimal representation: $1, 1.4, 1.41, ...$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the thing about the sequence of decimal approximations is that it is not obvious how to compute the next term, except for testing all 10 digits.

Comment: @lhf I don't see that that's a problem, though - even if it's not as efficiently computable, it's much easier to understand *what* it is, and *why* it converges to $\sqrt{2}$, which I think addresses the OP's question well (which is not to say that yours doesn't).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, good point. Perhaps you can add your own answer.

Comment: @lhf I think that would be pointless - this answer is absolutely right (and I upvoted btw).

Answer (score 5):

You can always define $x^y$ for $x>0$ by taking the formal logarithm and defining it in order to maintain the functional property of the logarithm:

$$\log x^y = y\log x$$

so you define:

> $$x^y := \exp(y\log x)$$

In your case, it gives $3^\sqrt{2} = \exp(\sqrt{2}\log 3)$.

Answer (score 4):

$3^{\sqrt{2}}= sup\{3^q \,| \, q \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge q^2<2 \}$

Answer (score 2):

$3^{\sqrt2}$ is $e^{\sqrt2\cdot\ln3}$, where "$e$" is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ and "$\ln$" is the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) function.